# Filter data in CSV read in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this CSV to read, but I need to filter the groupby values by column 'State' where 'Updated On' values is 24/04/2021, but I don't know how.

```
  acoesEstado = pd.read_csv("https://api.covid19india.org/csv/latest/statewise_tested_numbers_data.csv", index_col=0)
    filtro = acoesEstado.groupby(['State']).sum(Updated On  = '25/04/2021').reset_index()
    filtro['Total Tested']
```

I want the output: select all States where Updated On = 24/04/2021

Comment: Please add the (sample) output you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, i want the output: select all States where Updated On = 24/04/2021, thnxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for Sum of Total Tested by State for 24/04/2021.

```
df.loc['24/04/2021'].groupby('State')['Total Tested'].sum()
```

**Considering Input:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://api.covid19india.org/csv/latest/statewise_tested_numbers_data.csv", index_col=0)
```

**Sample Output:

```
State
Andaman and Nicobar Islands           0.0
Andhra Pradesh                 15931722.0
Arunachal Pradesh                434293.0
Assam                           8240455.0
Bihar                          25852574.0
```